# Is the android transform-api for gradle deprecated?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to use the transform-api for one of my android plugins. But when I look at the maven repositories for the dependencies, I find the latest version to be deprecated

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api

https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.android.tools.build%7Ctransform-api%7C2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api%7Cjar

The versioning says: **`2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api`**

What's this about? Are the APIs deprecated? Do the gradle buildsystem have a transform-api of it's own which should be used? I am not able to find any information about them anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:2.3.0-beta3'
```

(or another version from https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle-api)

Answer (score 0):

The tramsform api was moved to com.android.tools.build:gradle-api,check  http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/javadoc/current/.
And gradle-api is in google's own repository now.Assuming you are using gradle, you should add google() to the repositories in build.gradle.

```
repositories {
    google()
    //...other repositories
}
```

then add **implementation "com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.3.2"** in dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    //...other repositories
    implementation "com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.3.2"
}
```